# AmCharts is not display chart with Json datasource

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I have two charts in ASP.Net MVC web application with Json datasource. I'm using amcharts to display the graphs.

In the first case it's working:

The javascript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        LoadVisual();
    });

    function LoadVisualAjax() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetReport5GraphData", "Report")',
        });
    }

    function LoadVisual() {
             $.when(LoadVisualAjax()).then((data) => {
                 DrawChart(data);
             }).fail(() => {
                 alert("Fail to initialize Chart");
             });
    }

    function DrawChart(dataVal) {
        console.log(dataVal);

        var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
            {
                "type": "serial",
                "categoryField": "gep",
                "startDuration": 1,
                "backgroundAlpha": 0.8,
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "autoRotateAngle": 0,
                    "gridPosition": "start"
                },
                "trendLines": [],
                "graphs": [
                    {
                        "balloonColor": "#008000",
                        "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                        "fillAlphas": 1,
                        "fillColors": "#428542",
                        "id": "AmGraph-1",
                        "legendColor": "#008000",
                        "lineColor": "undefined",
                        "markerType": "triangleUp",
                        "title": "ok",
                        "type": "column",
                        "valueField": "ok"
                    },
                    {
                        "animationPlayed": true,
                        "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                        "bulletColor": "#008000",
                        "customMarker": "",
                        "fillAlphas": 1,
                        "id": "AmGraph-2",
                        "labelText": "",
                        "markerType": "triangleDown",
                        "minDistance": 0,
                        "title": "selejt",
                        "type": "column",
                        "valueField": "selejt"
                    }
                ],
                "guides": [],
                "valueAxes": [
                    {
                        "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                        "stackType": "regular",
                        "title": "Gyártott mennyiség (db)"
                    }
                ],
                "allLabels": [],
                "balloon": {},
                "legend": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "useGraphSettings": true
                },
                "titles": [
                    {
                        "id": "Title-1",
                        "size": 15,
                        "text": "Előző műszakban gyártott mennyiség"
                    }
                ],
            "dataProvider": dataVal
        });
        chart.addListener("rendered");
    }
</script>
```

The dataVal variable value (from MVC controller):

Working

[image: Working]

In the second case the chart is not displaying:

The javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function LoadVisualAjax() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetReport3Data", "Report")',
        });
    }

    function LoadVisual() {
             $.when(LoadVisualAjax()).then((data) => {
                 DrawChart(data);
             }).fail(() => {
                 alert("Fail to initialize Chart");
             });
         }

    function DrawChart(dataVal) {
            console.log(dataVal);

            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginRight": 40,
            "marginLeft": 40,
            "autoMarginOffset": 20,
            "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "position": "left",
                "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
                "title": "Darabszám",
                "position": "left",
                "autoGridCount": false,
                "labelFunction": function (value) {
                    return Math.round(value);
                }
            }],
            "balloon": {
                "borderThickness": 1,
                "shadowAlpha": 0,
            },
            "graphs": [{
                "id": "AmGraph-1",
                "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                "hideBulletsCount": 50,
                "lineThickness": 2,
                "title": "Cím ",
                "type": "column",
                "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
                "valueField": "Db",
                "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b style='font-size: 130%'>[[value]]</b>",
            }],
            "valueScrollbar": {
                "oppositeAxis": false,
                "offset": 50,
                "scrollbarHeight": 10
            },
            "categoryField": "ErrorCode",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "parseDates": false,
                "equalSpacing": true,
                "minPeriod": "DD",
                "dashLength": 1,
                "minorGridEnabled": true,
            },
            "legend": {
                "useGraphSettings": true,
                "position": "top"
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": false,
            },
            "dataProvider": dataVal
            });

        }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        LoadVisual();
    });
```

The dataVal variable value (from MVC controller):

Wrong

[image: Wrong]

What is the difference? Why is my second chart not rendering?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

AmCharts expects an array of objects in the `dataProvider`. The first one works because it's just an array of objects; the second one is an object containing several properties in addition to an array. Change the second chart to reference the array inside your dataVal variable (`"dataProvider": dataVal.Data`) and it will work.